# How to use friend function or friend class?

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CBase
{   
    public:
    int a;
    int b;
    private:
    int c;
    int d;
    protected:
    int e;
    int f;
    //friend int cout1();
 };

class CDerived : public CBase
{
    public:
    friend class CBase;
    int cout1()
    {
        cout << "a" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        cout << "b" << endl;
        cin >> b;
        cout << "c" << endl;
        cin >> c;
        cout << "d" << endl;
        cin >> d;
        cout << "e" << endl;
        cin >> e;
        cout << "f" << endl;
        cin >> f;
        cout << a << "" << b << "" << c << "" << d << "" << e << "" << f << "" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CDerived chi;
    chi.cout1();
}
```

How to use friend class and friend function? Please help me out. I have many similar errors:

```
c6.cpp: In member function int CDerived::cout1():
c6.cpp:10: error: int CBase::c is private
c6.cpp:30: error: within this context
  c6.cpp:11: error: int CBase::d is private
c6.cpp:32: error: within this context
  c6.cpp:10: error: int CBase::c is private
c6.cpp:37: error: within this context
  c6.cpp:11: error: int CBase::d is private
c6.cpp:37: error: within this context
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CDerived` cannot access the private members of `CBase`. It doesn't matter if you make it a friend or not. If you want such access to be allowed, you have to make `CBase` declare the friendship relationship.

```
#include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  class CDerived; // Forward declaration of CDerived so that CBase knows that CDerived exists

  class CBase
  {   
  public:
      int a;
      int b;
  private:
      int c;
      int d;
  protected:
      int e;
      int f;

      friend class CDerived; // This is where CBase gives permission to CDerived to access all it's members
 };

 class CDerived : public CBase
 {

 public:
 void cout1()
 {
        cout<<"a"<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"b"<<endl;
        cin>>b;
        cout<<"c"<<endl;
        cin>>c;
        cout<<"d"<<endl;
        cin>>d;
        cout<<"e"<<endl;
        cin>>e;
        cout<<"f"<<endl;
        cin>>f;
        cout<<a<<""<<b<<""<<c<<""<<d<<""<<e<<""<<f<<""<<endl;
  } 
};

int main()
{
    CDerived chi;
    chi.cout1();
}
```

Comment: You'll need to make cout1 return something too to make it compile

Comment: Thanks, another example of why you shouldn't just copy-paste. (It's about time I learned that lesson)

Comment: thanks a lot. .can you please help out with friend member fuc. .

Comment: You cannot make a member function of CDerived a friend of CBase. In order to do that, CDerived must be fully defined but since CDerived is derived from CBase, CBase must be fully defined. So, you have a viscious circle.

I think you need to rethink the design of your classes here. Good programming practice says that CBase must know absolutely nothing about any classes that are derived from it. If you need derived classes to access members, you either make them protected, or you give a protected access method that returns a read-only copy of the underlying data.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for you is to make the fields you access from the base class protected, not private. Still if you want to use `friend`, you have to make `CDerived` a friend class to the class `CBase`.

Comment: Note that there's no way to make `CDerived::cout1` a friend of `CBase`; it would introduce mutual dependence on definitions.

Comment: @Angew true. I will remove that

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
class CDerived : public CBase
 {

    public:
    friend class CBase;
```

That means that `CBase`has access to `CDerived`'s private members, not the other way around. Depending on your design, perhaps it is better to make those members `protected`. Else you need to declare `CDerived` as a friend of `CBase`.

Answer (score 0):

When You're writing

```
friend class CBase;
```

it means that CBase can access private methods of CDerived. What You want to do here is to write

```
friend class CDerived
```

in CBase, so CDerived could use private methods of CBase

Answer (score 0):

If you want class `B` to bypass the encapsulation of class `A`, then `A` must declare `B` as a `friend`, not the other way around.